# SQLAlchemy doesn't recognize new entries in query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm querying the latest entry from a table like this:

```py
data = dbsession.query(db.mytable).order_by(db.mytable.timestamp.desc()).with_entities(db.mytable.timestamp).first()
```

On startup this is fine, but if new etries are added by the same dbsession during runtime, the query above doesn't recognize them.
But the following code without SQLAlchemy works as expected:

```py
sql_query="SELECT timestamp FROM mytable ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1"
data = cursor.execute(sql_query)
```

How do I get SQLAlchemy to work in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a similar issue once, without recalling exactly why sqlAlchemy behaves this way, you need to commit the session before the select to refresh the data:

```
session.commit()
```

Comment: I'm doing the commit after adding a new entry. Do you know why I have to do this again right before the new query?

Comment: Not so much why SQLAlchemy behaves this way, but why SQL works this way: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems). Comes up with SQLA sessions, because they're (almost) always transactional, as opposed to having some form of auto commit enabled.